# How do I verify Apache caching is working?

Tags: apache, caching, apache2, httpd.conf

I've added the cache directives to my httpd.conf file but cannot discover how to verify it's actually caching the pages and serving them up. How can I verify this?

I added the cache directives at the server config level (not using VirtualHost) as:

```
CacheEnable disk /
CacheRoot /var/cache
CacheDefaultExpire 3600
```

Answer (score 7):

You can check if your apache is really caching content or not by confirming below points.

1. check size of /var/cache directory. It should be growing in size after some time when there is hit on your apache
2. You can check in logs, there should response code 302 instead of 200.

If you match both these points then there should be working mod_disk_cache module.

Comment: Thank you. I'm seeing an empty folder and `200`. How do I figure out what's wrong?

Comment: Is this correct? Checking on google search, cached pages can show as code `200`. Do you have a source for the `302` code?

Comment: I think you meant 304 and not 302. 302 is redirect.

Answer (score 4):

If you add `\"%{cache-status}e\"` to your LogFormat line it will show up in your access log file.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply write a quick php page.  If you refresh the page the time in the upper right should not grow for another 300 seconds.

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, max-age=300");
header("Vary: Accept-Encoding");
echo time()."<br>";
?>
```

Comment: This does not work for me, but it is strange. I made two files, `dynamic.php` with your code and `static.html` with the text "hello world". When I open the files in my browser the caching works correctly for static.html, but does not work for dynamic.php. However, in both cases, the correct files are created in the server cache on the disk, but for some reason apache does not use the cache. This means that EVEN IF the cache is correctly created on disk, apache may NEVER use it, and just keeps refreshing it. There must be another setting missing. Researching this on google is very hard!

Answer (score 2):

304 in the logs does not mean that your content is served from cache. But yes looking at the folder /var/cache/mod_proxy you can see contents and size growing.

In httpd.conf add this

```
SetEnv CACHE_MISS 1
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %{CACHE_MISS}e" combined
```

Now my log changes as below

Before

```
192.xx.xx.xx - - [29/Oct/2015:10:11:12 -0400] "GET /pathToResource/javascript/extjs/lib/extjs4/ext-all.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "https://my-url" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36"
```

After changes as described above

```
192.xx.xx.xx - - [29/Oct/2015:10:11:12 -0400] "GET /pathToResource/javascript/extjs/lib/extjs4/ext-all.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "https://my-url" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36" 1
```

Notice 1 at the end.
Next time if you do F5 in your browser , you should see the same resource being served and there will be not be **1** at end.

Answer (score 1):

A simple test to verify a working cache:

- Request a URL, e.g. `curl "http://mydomain/my/page?test_param"`
- Check that the HTTP status code is either 200, 203, 300, 301 or 410 (only those are cached, see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/caching.html)
- Check the cache with htcacheclean, e.g. `htcacheclean -p /var/cache -A|grep 'test_param'`

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below settings.

```
<IfModule mod_cache.c>
LoadModule cache_disk_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_cache_disk.so
<IfModule mod_disk_cache.c>
CacheDefaultExpire 3600
CacheEnable disk /
CacheRoot "/path/to/cache/folder/"
CacheDirLevels 2
CacheDirLength 1
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I did and the group that apache user is a member of it's the owner and had read and write access

Comment: I hope you would have loaded below two modules as well in httpd.conf file. "mod_disk_cache" "mod_cache"

Comment: Please try with below settings.

&lt;IfModule mod_cache.c&gt;
LoadModule cache_disk_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_cache_disk.so
&lt;IfModule mod_disk_cache.c&gt;
CacheDefaultExpire 3600
CacheEnable disk /
CacheRoot "/path/to/cache/folder/"
CacheDirLevels 2
CacheDirLength 1
&lt;/IfModule&gt;
&lt;/IfModule&gt;

Answer (score 0):

```
CacheRoot "/var/cache/folder"
```

check

> /var/log/apache2/error.log

if there any permission error, it wont write in the Directory, give apache2  permissions to that directory like below

```
mkdir -p /var/cache/folder/
chown root:www-data /var/cache/apache2/mod_cache_disk/ -R
chmod 775 /var/cache/apache2/mod_cache_disk/ -R
```

access the pages  check in folder there will be directory structure will appear and there are two files one for header and another for data. if it will show like the data is caching other wise configuration something missing, i configured this is working, cached pages also showing 200 status in log in my case

Answer (score 0):

Had the same challenge and the answers and comments here was very helpful.
Another option that I also found useful while testing, is adding one or more of the Apace caching headers.

- [CacheHeader](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_cache.html#cacheheader)
- [CacheDetailHeader](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_cache.html#cachedetailheader)

They make it easy to test and verify the setup using a basic http client (e.g. curl).